# Classic record type selection page is not converted to lightning mode

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, record-type

We recently migrated our instance to lightning, everything is working well and UI of all standard page layouts got converted to lightning. But one problem is when we initiate new record creation which have multiple record types, we will be getting an intermediate page to select record types.

But this intermediate page for record type selection is still looking in old classic style but not in lightning style.This is killing the user experience where half things are coming in lightning and half in old classic style.

Is there any way to convert this page into lightning mode?

Comment: Still some standard pages are in classic mode.

Comment: @RohitMourya Thanks Rohit, do you see way to achieve this , seems to be overriding New button with a VF page with LDS design may not work here as pagereference function is not supported in lightning